# Properties of linear matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am not sure if this is completely ill defined, and not much can be said about. Any pointer/suggestion would be helpful.

Suppose $T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m < n$ ("fat matrix") and $K_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $K_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

Can one say what properties $K_1$ and $K_2$ should satisfy for
$$
   TK_1 =K_2T
$$

Comment: Assuming that $T^TT$ is invertible, the property they must possess is $$K_1 = (T^TT)^{-1}T^TK_2T.$$ $K_2$ can be picked arbitrarily and $K_1$ calculated by the formula. More generally, when $T^TT$ is not invertible, you can still pick $K_2$ arbitrarily, but now there are multiple $K_1$ that will work with it, so an additional arbitrary choice is needed. Since $m < n$, $TT^T$ cannot be invertible, but $T$ can still have pseudo-inverses that would allow you to pick $K_1$ arbitrarily and find $K_2$.

Comment: Gosh, why didn't I think about the pseudo inverse, one wonders! Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The problem with slinging snot around is that it gets in your eyes, and then you can't see what is right in front of you. So why don't you wipe it off, read again, this time, note what I am actually saying.

Comment: Thanks, my comment on pseudo-inverse is only driven by the fact that in a specific case I am considering $T^TT$ is indeed not invertible but $T$ does indeed have a pseudo-inverse.